How to based on the known output, to obtain the Bazel build target
If I have a known out/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/**/*.ko file, how can I obtain the corresponding bazel build target or the source files of its compilation dependencies? Thanks.
I can get the dependencies if I know the build taget by bazel query, But I don't konw the what is the build taget now.
